# Copy a large file from other source to Azure Blob using URI in Shell

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I need to copy a large file(100 GB) from other source to Azure Blob using Shell/Cloud Shell. I have URI of file from internet but I am not aware of process. My current approach of wget to cloud shell and then upload to blob is not working owing to 5GB size restriction. I am aware of downloading to my local system and then uploading to blob but I am looking for a robust solution.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really have to download this large file and re-upload it. You can use `Azure Copy Blob` functionality that can create a blob from any publicly available URL. For this, you will need to use [`az storage blob copy start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob/copy?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-copy-start) command.

Here's an example of the same:

```
az storage blob copy start --account-key <your-account-key> --account-name <your-storage-account-name> --destination-blob <your-blob-name> --destination-container <your-blob-container-name> --source-uri <URI of the large file>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Have been trying it for a while. I have a question with it, whenever I am running the command, I get a message saying "status": "pending". How can I know once the upload is completed. I am new to Azure.

Comment: I found the way to identify job status. Here is the command.

`az storage blob show --container-name <container-name> --name <blob name>`